# Knockout X-Editable success handler is not called

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-validation, x-editable

I have a column in a table with knockout x-editable bind values. After page load and as a result of ko binding the success handler is called for each row (which is fine, I can avoid that). But once the page is set up, and I go ahead and change a value (set any of the row's employeeId to a 7 digit number), the success handler is not called any more. See this fiddle with opened console log:

http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/y3rfe6Lw/6/

HTML:

```
<table style="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: candidates">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="editable: employeeId, editableOptions: { validate: $root.validateEmployeeId, success: $root.persistEmployeeId($data) }"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.validateEmployeeId = function (value) {
            if (value == null || !value.match(/^\d{7}$/))
                return 'Invalid EmployeeID';
        }

        self.persistEmployeeId = function (data) {
            console.log(data.employeeId);
        }

        self.candidates = ko.observableArray([
            { firstName: "John", lastName: "Dow", employeeId: 1001, applicantId: 1 },
            { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", employeeId: 1002, applicantId: 2 },
            { firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar", employeeId: 1003, applicantId: 3 }
        ]);
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

});
```

I need to persist the data change though. I tried to workaround this problem by making employeeId ko.observable and subscribing to the change event of it. But with the subscribe I only receive the newValue as a parameter. I would need the data row, and the applicantId from it. The employeeId might not be unique, and I need to the persistence API call needs applicantId and employeeId.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't do what you were trying to do with the `success` binding (I don't think you can do it) but I instead just used Knockout with a `subscribe`.

Declare `Applicant` ViewModel as we need employeeId to be an observable to subscribe to:

```
var Applicant = function (model) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = model.firstName;
    self.lastName = model.lastName;
    self.employeeId = ko.observable(model.employeeId);
    self.applicantId = model.applicantId;

    self.employeeId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        console.debug('Applicant ' + self.applicantId + ' now has employeeId: ' + newValue);
    });
}
```

Change the candidates arrray population to use the Applicant ViewModel instead:

```
var candidates = [
    new Applicant({ firstName: "John", lastName: "Dow", employeeId: 1001, applicantId: 1 }),
    new Applicant({ firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", employeeId: 1002, applicantId: 2 }),
    new Applicant({ firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar", employeeId: 1003, applicantId: 3 })
];

self.candidates = ko.observableArray(candidates);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp24fuk6/)

Comment: Oh, ok. So I encapsulate the rows into an Applicant "object" and then I can refer to the applicantId using self. I'll do that. I still wonder why the success handler stops working.

Comment: It stops working because you are assigning it wrong. You can't use success: $root.persistEmployeeId($data) it needs to be success: $root.persistEmployeeId. According to the documentation you can only get the new value and that is all

Comment: Hmmm, but if you look at the console log, three notifications arrive in the beginning, carrying the $data. So why it works for a while then? Anyways...